# CardView elevation nullified by background?

Tags: android, androidx, cardview

I'm doing some mock-up design using `CardView` when I found an issue. When I set a background color on the `CardView` in any way(android:backgroundColor, app:cardBackgroundColor, card_view:cardBackgroundColor), the elevation shadow seems to be gone or not as noticeable as I expected. I also already added `android:hardwareAccelerated` on my manifest and `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` on the `CardView` and it still looks the same, which is no shadow on the `CardView`.

Here's my layout's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_500"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This actually works, when you will run your app on android then I am sure you will find this working.

If your shadow opacity is too low then try to increase your **cardElevation** and you can make dark shadow by using -

```
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#000000"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#000000"
```